# Google App Script Silently fails to POST, Curl Works

Tags: api, post, google-apps-script, urlfetch, jive

Curl is posting but Google AppScript is not with the same credentials.

Am trying to get google app script to post the current document as html content to a new Jive Document

// The following curl command works flawlessly

```
curl -u USERNAMEHERE:PASSWORDHERE -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "type": "document", "content": { "type": "text/html", "text":"<h1>HOORAY</h1> a Document is born"}, "subject": "TEST WORKED"}' https://MYJIVEURL.com/api/core/v3/places/XXXXXXXX/contents
```

// Apps Script is now throwing a 401 and failing

````
function pleaseWork() {
  var encode = Utilities.base64Encode('USER:PASS', Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
  var docbody = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var subject = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getName();
  var url = "https://JIVEURL/api/core/v3/places/XXXXXX/contents";

  var option = {
    authorization: "Basic " + encode,
    contentType: "application/json",
    method: 'post',
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      subject: subject,
      type: "document",
      content: {
        type: 'text/html',
        text: docbody
      },
    })
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, option).getContentText()

}```




Theres no other errors to speak of in the AppScript editor. So I must be leaving something out. I just don't know what that is
````

Comment: What are the acceptable parameters in `option` according to official urlfetch documentation?

Comment: Please don't edit your question to invalidate the answer already provided. [Edit] to add additional information and  Do not delete old information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part 1 - `payload`**

`params` object has a parameter called "payload" that should contain data you are going to send as a stringified JSON. Thus, instead of direct reference of the `content`, `subject` and `type`, you should do the following (btw, content type for `UrlFEtchApp` can be set via `contentType` parameter and the `method` via the corresponding parameter):

```
var option = {
  //other parameters here;
  method : 'post',
  contentType : 'application/json',
  payload : JSON.stringify( {
  content : '',
  subject : '',
  type    : ''
  } )
}
```

**Part 2 - `headers`**

Though it may seem arbitrary, *not all* of the parameters should be moved to top-level properties of the `params` object. There is a closed set of properties that can be set this way (see reference). Authorization should still be set as a `header`, thus:

```
var option = {
  //other parameters here;
  headers : {
    Authorization : 'Basic ' + yourAuth
  },
  method : 'post',
  contentType : 'application/json',
  payload : JSON.stringify( {
    content : '',
    subject : '',
    type    : ''
  } )
}
```

**Useful links**

1. `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object));

Comment: Hi, @AndyFitzsimon! Please, clarify, what exactly you meant by your comment? (OK, got the update - let me know if it works for you - other than wrapping everything in payload, there shouldn't be any problems)

Comment: Well There's some 'progress' . 401 request failed.  At least something is happening.

I'm guessing the authorization is now an issue not the option object

Comment: function pushItGood() {
      var encode = Utilities.base64Encode('USER:PASS', Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
      var url = "https://TESTDOMAIN.com/api/core/v3/places/XXXXXX/contents";
      var option = {
        authorization: "Basic " + encode,
        contentType: "application/json",
        method: 'post',
        payload: JSON.stringify({
          subject: 'testing',
          type: "document",
          content: {
            type: 'text/html',
            text: 'testinghere'
          },
        })
      }
     ........

Comment: Andy, please, update your question with the new structure of the code and I'll take a look (its hard to look through unformatted code) - if you are getting 401, then its the authorization that's causing issues now

Comment: Thank you,  it's updated in the question . 

The appropriate  USER/PASS and URL's in my testing reflect what I use  in my CURL commands

Comment: Andy, that's easy, I'll update the answer in a second!

Comment: That would be tremendously appreciated!

Comment: Don't mention! I've updated the answer, with this everything should work like a charm.

Comment: NP! If you are accustomed to how the requests are usually handled in JS, `UrlFetchApp` usage might be a bit confusing)

Comment: I actually had a bounty open for this and got no responses. 
[All yours if you click answer and type anything as the solution](https://bountify.co/google-app-script-docs-document-to-jive-rest-api-document)

Comment: Thanks, but leave it be - it's and open community here and we glad to help - just always accept the answer if it helped you as a small courtesy :)

Comment: cool mate, done.  you effectively just made a 50 USD donation to the Against Malaria Foundation.  Thanks again for solving this on behalf of everyone who groks CURL  but not Google's App Script apps

Comment: Glad to help! Don't hesitate to ask the community if you encounter any trouble (though, always include the script sample / research effort)